What does it mean that /sys/block/sda/stat shows 'write I/Os' nonzero values, but 'write sectors' is 0 value
This is the output of cat /sys/block/sda/stat :
3227140 166605 7596010579 28294594 51 0 0 656 2 15228780 28295907 0 0 0 0 51 656.

Column 5 is 'write I/Os' currently 51, column 7 is 'write sectors' currently 0.
So was something written to the drive or not? Did any sectors change? Or what does the 51 'write I/Os' mean while 'write sectors' is still zero?
